# JsonIgnore Attribute ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, model

I would like to make the [JsonIgnore] attribute cause properties with this annotation not to be returned by the API. For example, in the User model, the API does not return the password. However, the [JsonIgnore] attribute must not cause sent properties to be ignored. How to do it?

Comment: Don't expose your database models publicly. Instead, use a DTO to expose it from your API.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know the method and I would never have guessed it myself. Thanks again!